# Como se usa e para que serve a propriedade user-select

Tags: css, front-end

Eu estou aprendendo front-end e me deparei [nesse site](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Cool-Morphing-Sidebar-Navigation-with-jQuery-CSS3.html) com uma propriedade CSS chamada `user-select`, eu não entendi para que serve e não consegui encontrar uma boa explicação.

Queria que me explicassem para que serve, como e quando usar esse `user-select`. Não somente no caso citado no site acima.

Comment: lol por que editar e tirar a linha que eu agradeço pela ajuda? É contra as regras ser educado?

Comment: Por que não é relevante para a dúvida.

Comment: A resposta do @MeuChapeu está bem completa, apenas para complementar, verifique qual(is) e que versão(ões) de navegador você pretende utilizar, pois as versões mais antigas não permitem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

De maneira simples o `user-selection` serve para controlar o conteúdo que pode ser selecionado no site.

### Valores

User-select aceita quatro valores:

**text** – o texto pode ser selecionado

**element** – o texto pode ser selecionado, ficando restrito aos limites do elemento

**none** – o texto não pode ser selecionado

**auto** – se o elemento contiver texto editável, como um elemento de entrada ou elemento com conteúdo editável, o texto pode ser selecionado. Outras formas de seleção são determinadas pelo valor do nó pai.

### Exemplos

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: text;

-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: text;

-ms-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: text;
-ms-user-select: element;
```

`-moz`, `-webkit`, `-ms` essas "marcações" na frente do `user-select` são referentes a cada navegador.

`-moz` para mozilla
`-ms` para internet explorer
`-webkit` para chrome

### Quando usar

Você pode usar quando sentir a necessidade de controlar o conteúdo que é selecionado no site.

Neste [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20150428071343/http://ie.microsoft.com:80/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/) ele mostra como funciona os diferentes tipos que o `user-select` suporta.

Neste [site](https://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none) tem uma tabela mostrando quais os browsers que tem suporte e suas referidas versões.

**Referências:**

[MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie_br/archive/2012/01/17/controlando-a-sele-231-227-o-com-a-css-user-select.aspx)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

Answer (score 12):

Viva!

A propriedade CSS `user-select` serve para controlares que texto é que o utilizador pode ou não pode seleccionar.

## Valores

**auto:**
Controlado pelo browser, o comportamento pode ser diferente dependendo do browser que está a ser utilizado.

**element:**
O utlizador apenas pode seleccionar o conteúdo que esteja dentro do elemento.

**none:**
O utilizador não podes seleccionar conteúdo nenhum.

**text:**
O utlizador apenas pode seleccionar o texto que esteja dentro do elemento.

---

## Browser Support

**Chrome:** Todas as versões.

**Safari:** Todas as versões.

**Firefox:** Todas as versões.

**Opera:** Versão 27 ou superior.

**IE:** Versão 10 ou superior.

**Android:** Versão 4.1 ou superior.

**iOS:** Versão 7.1 ou superior.

---

## Exemplo

Um exemplo onde essa propriedade pode ser útil é quando se pretender oferecer ao utilizador uma forma mais simples de fazer copy|paste. Evitando assim que sejam seleccionadas coisas inúteis como por exemplo imagens.

Um site onde podes ler mais sobre essa propriedade é: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select.

Deixo-te aqui um pequeno exemplo prático que encontrei, para tentar facilitar a compreensão daquilo que tentei explicar:

```css
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="unselectable">Não vais conseguir seleccionar este texto!</p>
```

---

### Fontes

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: Boa, eu estava vendo esse mesmo conteúdo pra explicar como resposta hehe. Talvez poderia editar e colocar mais informações(como os parâmetros aceitos e os navegadores/versões em que ele funciona) para os usuários mais 'preguiçosos'.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, já adicionei! ;)